# AHK - Modify #Options with Hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a possibilty to combine Hotsrting settings with Hotkeys ?
([i]Without duplicating all hotstrings ofcourse And without adding extra lines to hotstrings[/i])
I can imagine ways, but only by duplicating everything. 

Reason:
 
I would like to use normal space to fire hotsring in a way, that the space is added at the end, 
but i want to use Alt+Space if i want to use it as  ":o:"
(Actually it would be very nice to know how in general a Hotkey could be used to modify some #Options.)

```
[u]Something like this: [/u]<br>
#"if Alt is pressed"
{
#Hotkey o 
}
::hlo::Hello!
::wtv::Whatever
```

Alternatively it could add a BS after the end, like:

```
~!space::send,{bs}   ;(this does not work together with the hotsrting ofcourse)
```

Instead of something like this:

```
::hlo::
{
if alt is pressed...else ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
So we have discussed this together for quite some time on the Discord AHK forum.
Answers so far to different aspects of my question:
- You cannot Modify any #Options directly
- But it is possible to modify Hotkeys/Hotsrings etc. on the fly via specific functions.
- In case of Hotstrings a very new feature is also the use of :x:abc::, that allows the use of expressions -> and in that we can call a function, that uses GlobalVariables -> Via those variables the settings can be adjusted dynamically, before run. 
- My final solution to the particular problem was very different though. Instead of using inbuilt options, I had better luck with a nasty workaround:

```
#inputlevel 1
!space:: 
{
        SendInput,{space}
        sleep 0
        SendInput,{bs}
return
}
#inputlevel 0
::asd::by the way
```

- Also pasting one of the codes @CliveGalway (a.k.a EvilC?) helped me with via the forum. The reason I could not use it in this particular case is that if :x: is used, the hotstring loses its automatic CaseSensitivity - and i did not want that... otherwise excellent script:

```
#SingleInstance force
EndCharOn := 0
SetCapsLockState, Off

hotStrings := [{hs: "btw", rep: "By the Way"}
                ,{hs: "tat", rep: "This and That"}]

for i, h in hotStrings {
    HotString(":X:" h.hs, Func("SendHotString").Bind(h.rep))
}

CapsLock::
    EndCharOn := !EndCharOn
    SetCapsState()
    return

SetCapsState(){
    global EndCharOn
    SetCapsLockState, % (EndCharOn ? "On" : "Off")
}

SendHotString(Text){
    global EndCharOn
    SendRaw, % Text (EndCharOn ? A_EndChar : "")
    EndCharOn := 0
    SetCapsState()
}

^Esc::
    ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are saying. I *think* you want `#if`

```
#if GetKeyState("Alt") ; Only enable these hotstrings if Alt is held
::hlo::Hello!
::wtv::Whatever
#if
```

Comment: Hi, you were EvilC from the forum, right? - I have tried to sum up in short, our relevant discussions above.

Comment: Ill give you still a point for this comment of yours, as an overall thanks for the efforts.